# If harmonic means of two random variables are equal, does arithmetic means of them are equal too?

Tags: random-variables, means

If there are two random variables whose harmonic means are equal,

does they have same arithmetic mean?

In other words,

If $E[\frac{1}{X}]=E[\frac{1}{Y}]$, then $E[X]=E[Y]$?

Assuming that we know their harmonic means and arithmetic means are non-zero.

Comment: Obviously not. A simple counterexample would be $X= $ "1 or 2 with probability 50% 50%", and $Y=4/3$ with probability 100%.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks for your helpful comment!